# How do I put infowindow contents into a separate `div`?

Tags: javascript, carto, carto-js, infowindow

I'm new to CartoJS. When a user clicks a dot on my CartoDB map, I want the content of the infowindow to appear in a separate `div` on the web page.

How do I do this with CartoDB/JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CARTO.js method `addInfowindow()`, as explained [here](https://carto.com/docs/faqs/infowindows/#how-can-i-use-cartojs-to-create-and-style-infowindows) (for more info [here](https://carto.com/docs/carto-engine/carto-js/ui-functions/#cartodbvisvisaddinfowindowmap-layer-fields--options)).

```
cdb.vis.Vis.addInfowindow(map object to add enable the infowindow, 
layer to enable infowindow, ['fields to get information'])
```

However, you can create custom infowindows with different tools (Moustache, HTML, underscore). Whatever choice you use, you would need to create a template first and then add the infowindow with the template. [Here](http://bl.ocks.org/oriolbx/3950e1a9b458a9177f9c) you have a working example using an HTML template.